# Correct build python PIP package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

How to process the correct build of my application to PIP? 
I have done everything like a need in the documentation and it works, but after I have updates and my scripts changed from one to few (started from "**main**.py" script which imported others).

And my build process is broken now. How I able to fix this?

setup.py

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
     name='tests',  
     version='0.0.2',
     scripts=['tests'] ,
     author="Test",
     author_email="test@test.com",
     description="TEST",
     long_description=long_description,
   long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
     url="https://test.com",
     packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: Unix"
    ],
 )
```

Where "platops" is a directory with scripts.

Error

> error: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'tests'

How to correct build this?

Comment: Can you give us the actual `setup.py`? I can't find the problem when everything's been replaced with "test".

Comment: you never use `platops`. I suppose you want `scripts=['platops']` , or perhaps `packages=['platops']`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can't add a directory in `scripts=[]`. You can read up on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts). You will probably need to specify the relative path to each one.

From the docs:

```
Scripts are **files** containing Python source code, intended to be 

started from the command line.
```

Edit: You could also try using globbing:

```py
scripts=['scripts/*']
```